# error running builder in GaeNature, Google App Engine in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I get an intermittent error when launching Eclipse with an open GAE project. It prevents me from building my project. I can sometimes get it to clear by deleting the contents of the "war/WEB-INF/classes" folder and then restarting Eclipse. Sometimes I close the project, close eclipse, launch eclipse, open the project and that seems to help.  The error has been happening for several months and has persisted through a GAE plugin upgrade. I can usually get Eclipse to work eventually. Once it works it keeps working great until I relaunch it.

I am using GAE appengine-java-sdk-1.6.3
GWT 2.4.0
Objectify 3.1 (love it)
Eclipse Indigo SR2
Windows 7 64-bit

It feels like maybe a race condition when starting Eclipse.

Any ideas?

These errors occur during the build ======================

Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project '***'.
com/google/appengine/eclipse/core/nature/GaeNature

Errors running builder 'Google WebApp Project Validator' on project '***'.
java.lang.NullPointerException

Error instantiating builder 'com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.projectValidator'.

Plug-in com.google.appengine.eclipse.core was unable to load class com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.validators.GaeProjectValidator.

An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.google.appengine.eclipse.core (841).

Plug-in com.google.appengine.eclipse.core was unable to load class com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.validators.GaeProjectValidator.

An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.google.appengine.eclipse.core (841).

===================

I also got this error when trying to open the Google/App Engine properties dialog in Eclipse

Unable to create the selected property page.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.google.appengine.eclipse.core (841).

Comment: I have found that if I disable "Build Automatically" from the Project menu before I exit Eclipse then it will come up OK the next time. I can then turn on "Build Automatically" after the launch has completed. This happened 3-4 times. This supports the idea that there is a race condition between Eclipse launching and building the project. But because the problem is intermittent, it might just be a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this error today.
First I checked the project's properties to see if anything was out of place, but the Google App Engine tab wouldn't even open properly. It only gave a not-too-helpful error message:
`Unable to create the selected property page. An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.google.appengine.eclipse.core (7).`

After this I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Google App Engine SDK, and after restarting Eclipse the GAE worked just like it was supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. To fix this, I just created a new workspace in Eclipse.